# Getting execution exception for custom slick profile

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

Im' getting an exception when I try to use my own custom profile with slick. The reason why I want to use it is because I want to keep JSON in my postgresql database. Therefore, I'm using pg-slick. 
The exception says: 
slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$ cannot be cast to util.ExtendedPostgresProfile.

This is my code for the ExtendedPostgresProfile:

```
package util

import com.github.tminglei.slickpg._

trait ExtendedPostgresProfile extends ExPostgresProfile with PgPlayJsonSupport {

    override val api = new API with PlayJsonImplicits

    override def pgjson: String = "jsonb"
}

object ExtendedPostgresProfile extends ExtendedPostgresProfile
```

This is my DAO class:

```
class ActivityDAO @Inject()(dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {

    private val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[ExtendedPostgresProfile]

    import dbConfig._
    import profile.api._

    private class ActivityTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Activity](tag, "activity") {

        def id: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

        def activity: Rep[JsValue] = column[JsValue]("activity")

        def atTime: Rep[Timestamp] = column[Timestamp]("at_time")

        def activityTypeId: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("activiry_type_id")

        def userId: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("user_id")

        override def * : ProvenShape[Activity] =
            (id.?, activity, atTime.?, activityTypeId, userId.?) <> ((Activity.apply _).tupled, Activity.unapply)
    }

    private val activities = TableQuery[ActivityTable]

    def add(activity: Activity): Future[Long] = {

        val query = activities returning activities.map(_.id)

        db.run(query += activity)
    }

    def filter(userId: Long): Future[Seq[Activity]] = {

        db.run(activities.filter(_.userId === userId).result)
    }
}
```

I've tried searching for the answer my self, but haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 1):

Is your custom profile configured in your Play-slick configuration as suggested at the [Database Configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/PlaySlick#database-configuration) section? I.e. is it `util.ExtendedPostgresProfile$` or is it `slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$`?

Comment: In my application.conf it is setup with slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile. However, saving to the table doesn't work even for other DAOs which don't use my custom class

Comment: @Marin, what I'm saying is that your exception says that "_slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$ cannot be cast to util.ExtendedPostgresProfile_" which is a result of the fact that you have configured you profile that way. I expect that if you change your configuration to `util.ExtendedPostgresProfile` - it should start work.